# Are there any services for Audiobooks that have EU languages that work in the US?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, norwegian

Every service I've tried Storytel, Fabel, etc all are blocked in the US. While I'm sure this is because some US company has the rights, the US apps also only have English.

Is there any way to get an Audiobook service with Norwegian books in the US?

Comment: Just a note that Norway in particular does not belong to EU and Norwegian is not a EU language. (There is tight integration, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Still looking for alternatives, but at a minimum I just determined that for Norwegian specifically, [ebok.no](https://ebok.no/) has a premium service that let's you listen to anything you want.